# Error when directing the user to the settings menu to enable the gps service

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, geolocation

I am writing an app that uses the GPS service. I was making a test to check if the provider is enabling the service or not, in case the gps service is not enable, I am directing the user to the settings menu so they can activate it. I attempted to do so using the code posted below, but the problem is that, "ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" is always underscored with red and no suggestions are shown when I move the mouse pointer over it except an indication reads "Can not be resolved or is not a field".

JavaCode:

```
public class GPSTest00 extends ActionBarActivity {

private LocationManager locMgr;
boolean gpsEnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpstest00);

    locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    gpsEnable = locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnable) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Check your `import` statements, that you are importing the correct Android `Settings` class `android.provider.Settings`

Comment: true. android.provider.settings was not imported.